# Syntax error on multi query in NHibernate 3 and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I used to be able to run the following code as a multi query in NHibernate 2.1 using MySQL

```
var total = new LeagueInfoQuery { Count = true, User = CurrentUser }.CreateCriteria(session).FutureValue<int>();
var leagues = new LeagueInfoQuery { User = CurrentUser, PageSize = pageSize, Page = page, SortBy = sortBy, SortAsc = sortAsc }.CreateCriteria(session).Future<LeagueInfo>();
var results = PaginationHelper.CreateCustomPage<LeagueInfo>(leagues, pageSize, page, total.Value);
```

where e.g. LeagueInfoQuery is just a custom query object that can create a standard ICriteria.

However, since upgrading to NHibernate 3.0 I now get a syntax error. The exception message is as follows.

> {"Error executing multi criteria :
>   [SELECT count(*) as y0_ FROM `League`
>   this_ WHERE this_.User =
>   ?p0;\r\nSELECT this_.Id as y0_,
>   this_.Name as y1_, min(f1_.Date) as
>   y2_, max(f1_.Date) as y3_,
>   count(distinct t2_.Id) as y4_ FROM
>   `League` this_ inner join `Team` t2_
>   on this_.Id=t2_.League inner join
>   `Fixture` f1_ on this_.Id=f1_.League
>   WHERE this_.User = ?p1 GROUP BY
>   this_.Name ORDER BY y0_ desc limit
>   ?p1;\r\n]"}

Inner Exception:

> {"You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near
>   ''b68d9d4e-a958-4fb8-8490-9e4401572f38''
>   at line 1"}

So it looks like a syntax error but this didn't use to happen in v2.1 and if I edit the SQL in the message so that the parameters are values I can get it to work.

So why is this error now occurring in NHibernate 3.0? Do I need to configure something in particular for MySQL syntax and if so what?

Cheers.

Comment: If you can reproduce the issue consistently just by replacing the NH binaries, please open an issue at http://jira.nhforge.org

Comment: Ok I will do soon as I'm able, hopefully this evening - thanks.

Comment: I've created an issue with an attached project to demonstrates it http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-2450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with NHibernate 3 which has now been [resolved](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2450) (thanks!)